# How to use symbology to snowfall accumulation GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, imagery, climate

I haven't worked with raster data in a long time. I just downloaded the annual snowfall via GeoTIFF and import to ArcGIS Pro. Of course, it appeared in black and white. I am having trouble formatting the symbology to get it the same as the image. Do anyone have an idea how?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm missing something... doesn't the image you provided give you an exact list of colors and cutoff points for those colors?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these data are displayed  using a raster classification.  [Here is a link to classifying raster data in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/data/imagery/symbology-pane.htm).

After you manually set the classification bins to match the bins in your image you can then manually assign colors  to the different bins.  You could use [a color picking tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/color-picker) to determine the saturation values for the bins shown in the image above and then apply the same saturation values in Pro.